# Bind “Enter” key to WXPython "AquaButton" Button with Focus

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am new to this site and fairly new to Python. I am working on a program using wxPython for the GUI.  This is being developed and will be used on Windows OS machines.  The GUI uses a number of buttons that trigger different processes in my script. I decided to try using the AGW AquaButtons for visual interest.  I am finding that an "AquaButton" with focus will not respond to pressing the "Enter" key while the standard "wx.Button" does.  Below are examples (mostly borrowed from similar questions, thanks "Rolf of Saxony" and "Mike Driscoll") of the working and non-working code.

Is there a way to get an "AquaButton" (with Focus) have it's event triggered by the "Enter" key?

This works:

```
    import wx

    class Example(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, )
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(200,100))
            self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 1', id=1)
            self.btn1.SetForegroundColour("black")
            self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 2', id=2)
            self.btn2.SetForegroundColour("black")

            self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)
            self.sizer.Add(self.btn1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
            self.sizer.Add(self.btn2, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

            self.text_box = wx.StaticText(self.panel, style = wx.NO_BORDER)
            self.text_box.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
            self.text_box.SetForegroundColour((40,115,180))
            self.sizer.Add(self.text_box, pos=(2,0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_press)

            self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
            self.Show()

        def button_press(self, event):
            Id = event.GetId()
            print ('Click Button',str(Id))
            retVal = F"Click Button {Id}"
            self.text_box.SetLabel(str(retVal))


    class AppMenu(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
            'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
            frame = Example(None, 'Example')
            frame.Show(True)

            return True

    app = AppMenu()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This doesn't:

```
    import wx
    import wx.lib.agw.aquabutton as AB

    class Example(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, )
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(200,100))
            self.btn1 = AB.AquaButton(self.panel, label='Button 1', id=1)
            self.btn1.SetForegroundColour("black")
            self.btn2 = AB.AquaButton(self.panel, label='Button 2', id=2)
            self.btn2.SetForegroundColour("black")

            self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)
            self.sizer.Add(self.btn1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
            self.sizer.Add(self.btn2, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

            self.text_box = wx.StaticText(self.panel, style = wx.NO_BORDER)
            self.text_box.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
            self.text_box.SetForegroundColour((40,115,180))
            self.sizer.Add(self.text_box, pos=(2,0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_press)

            self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
            self.Show()

        def button_press(self, event):
            Id = event.GetId()
            print ('Click Button',str(Id))
            retVal = F"Click Button {Id}"
            self.text_box.SetLabel(str(retVal))


    class AppMenu(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
            'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
            frame = Example(None, 'Example')
            frame.Show(True)

            return True

    app = AppMenu()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bizarrely, the `AquaButton` is pressed using the Spacebar and not the Enter key.
Navigating appears to be via Arrow keys and/or Tab and Shift Tab.
If in doubt the source code is in:
`your_python_location/dist-packages/wx/lib/agw/aquabutton.py`

I hope that clears that up for you, if not for your users. :)

Comment: possible bug in agw?

Comment: Thanks @RolfofSaxony! I don't care to admit how long it took me to figure out that the functionality difference was being caused by the AquaButton to begin with, but I never would have figured out the whole spacebar thing.  Is modifying the binding in the library an option, or is that a no-no.

Comment: @JohnB If you copy the `aquabutton.py` into your local directory and edit it there, to your requirements, there is nothing to stop you including it in your package. It might be best if you called it `jb_aquabutton.py` so that you are aware of the difference at a later date.

Comment: @Igor I don't think so. The code is quite specific, although I can't account for it off the top of my head.

Comment: @JohnB I forgot to say that `Visual interest` will soon wear thin. It's probably best to stick with `mundane` but works. :)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I went ahead and created an "aquabutton2" and was able to modify a couple behaviors that I didn't care for.  Took me a minute to figure out what the " == ord(" ")" meant, but replacing that with "== wx.WXK_RETURN" did the trick. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, for the buttons it is the `standard` behavior to react on pressing the `Enter` key. It is weird if the control does not do anything when pressing Enter. It might be worth to at lest mention it on the wxPython ML. Maybe Robin can allow it based on some constructor parameter?